# getPrice() fatal error in magento customs product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

When I try to get the price attribute for the customs product, a fatal error is being thrown.

```
$_product->getPrice();

Fatal error: Call to a member function getPrice() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/SVE279/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php on line 211
```

When I checked in the core file, I found this:

```
public function getPriceModel()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton(‘catalog/product_type’)->priceFactory($this->getTypeId());
}
```

So the problem is with out customs product. Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: We need some details such as the priceFactory() function. It's difficult to know what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

You got this error when the $_product object is not properly loaded.

Example: load a product by "SKU"

> $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$row['sku']);
>   echo $product->getPrice();

Comment: hi i cant get the price for my custom product type only other product type's its working fine